# How to set Axis width and Heigth in AchartEngine Android?

Tags: android, graph, charts, achartengine

[image: This image]

(1) I want both X and Y axis width and height,
(2) I want X axis lables proper alignment
(3) I want to change colors of values text, Current is Orange and I want White.

My Code is:

```
private GraphicalView mView(Context ctx) {
        GraphicalView v = null;

        String[] titles = new String[] { "" };
        List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();

        double[] mDoubleArray = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };

        String[] X_Axis_Lables = { "07:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00",
                "12:00", "13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00", "18:00",
                "19:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00", "00:00", "01:00",
                "02:00", "03:00", "04:00", "05:00", "06:00", "07:00" };

        values.add(mDoubleArray);
        int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.actionbar_header_color);
        int[] colors = new int[] { color };

        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
        setChartSettings(renderer, "", "", "", 0, mDoubleArray.length, 0, 1,
                color, color, X_Axis_Lables);
        renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(0).setDisplayChartValues(true);
        renderer.setXLabels(0);
        renderer.setYLabels(1);
        renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
        renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
        renderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
        renderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
        renderer.setZoomRate(0.0f);
        renderer.setShowLegend(false);
        renderer.setBarWidth(10);
        renderer.setMarginsColor(getResources().getColor(
                R.color.transparent_background));
        renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        renderer.setXLabelsColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray));
        renderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.GRAY);

        v = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(ctx, buildBarDataset(titles, values),
                renderer, Type.STACKED);
        return v;

    }

    protected void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer,
            String title, String xTitle, String yTitle, double xMin,
            double xMax, double yMin, double yMax, int axesColor,
            int labelsColor, String[] x_Axis_Lables) {
        renderer.setChartTitle(title);
        renderer.setXTitle(xTitle);
        renderer.setYTitle(yTitle);
        renderer.setXAxisMin(xMin);
        renderer.setXAxisMax(xMax);
        renderer.setYAxisMin(yMin);
        renderer.setYAxisMax(yMax);

        for (int i = 0; i < x_Axis_Lables.length; i++) {
            renderer.addXTextLabel(i + 1, x_Axis_Lables[i]);

        }
        renderer.setXLabelsAngle(270);
        renderer.setLabelsTextSize(16);
        renderer.setAxesColor(axesColor);
        renderer.setLabelsColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray));
    }

    protected XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildBarRenderer(int[] colors) {
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
        renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
        renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
        renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
        int length = colors.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
            r.setColor(colors[i]);
            renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);

        }
        return renderer;
    }

    protected XYMultipleSeriesDataset buildBarDataset(String[] titles,
            List<double[]> values) {
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        int length = titles.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries(titles[i]);
            double[] v = values.get(i);
            int seriesLength = v.length;
            for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) {
                series.add(v[k]);
            }
            dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
        }
        return dataset;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    renderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLACK);
    renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
    renderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
    renderer.setYLabelsColor(0,Color.BLACK);
    renderer.setYAxisMax(200);
    renderer.setXAxisMax(200);
```